# AngularJS and .htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, angularjs, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using angularJs to build a website.

I have the following folder structure:

```
/
--index.html
--js
  --contoller.js
--css
  --style.css
--pages
  --homepage.html
  --faq.html
  --about.html
```

The relevant html on the index page is:

```
<div id="app">
    <div ng-view>
        <!-- this is where the views are injected -->
    </div>
</div>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="about/faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

The routing is:

```
obApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/homepage.html',
        controller  : 'homepageController'
    })
    // route for the about page
    .when('/about/faq', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/faq.html',
        controller  : 'faqController'
    })
    // route for the contact page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })
})
```

The .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now here's my problem:
When i access the links everything works perfectly - so it's ok. When i type into the browsers address bar the url `/about`, it works - ok again. When i do this however `/about/faq` i get everything to work, but the stylesheets are not loading. I've checked out the network response and it i get the wrong content type on them:

[image: response image]

As you can see the external link with the google font is loaded ok, only the local css files are sent with the wrong type.

My links are in the header as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >       
<!-- external font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

That being said, i'm stuck. I am developing this on a local machine and the url is something like this:

```
localhost/websites/angularProject
```

My guess is that the redirect needs something extra. (??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths instead.

**Your links**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/websites/angularProject/css/style.css" >
```

Do the same for your **js** and **images** links.

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <div ng-view>
        <!-- this is where the views are injected -->
    </div>
</div>
<li><a href="/websites/angularProject/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/websites/angularProject/about/faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

For your links, you could also use `<base href="/websites/angularProject/" />` html tag instead of replacing all links.

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /websites/angularProject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm developing this on localhost, where i have more than one website. My url on localhost is something like this "localhost/websites/angularProject". Your solution does not help me out of the binding i'm in. However i may not have been specific enough. Edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: That's not a problem, i edited my answer to make it work like you want

Comment: You are the man! Thank you very much - though the <a> need no modification. I think i need to catch up on apache mod_rewrite.

Comment: Follow up question, if you have the time. Why the heck did i see that behavior of resources being delivered with a different mime type? I mean, i sort of guessed where the problem was, but don't understand the cause(link to an article also works) - thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: This helped me so much. Been looking ages for this.